# Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a new React Native App using expo-cli and it doesn't normally have an index.js file, I tried to add one with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    
  <App />
    
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

which I was going to edit afterwards to work with React 18 but React Native doesn't work with "document.getElementById" so I searched and I found out that instead of index.js there is a file named AppEntry.js in the node_modules/expo which contains the following code:

```
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
import App from '../../App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

how to Edit it so It can work with React Native or is there any other fix?

Comment: That's not normal. You should't be having this error in React Native as there isn't `ReactDOM` needed it.

Comment: yes, I even searched `ReactDOM` in the whole project and couldn't find anything but yet it still gives me this warning

Comment: ProgrammerJohn's answer is correct for this, its a known Expo issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known issue and being investigated https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/18485